# Deleting record using SQL stored procedure from VB.net form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have written below code to delete record from multiple database tables but some how it is not deleting any record and doesn't display any error as well! can anyone help please?

```
    Private Sub btndelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndelete.Click
        Try
       cmd = New SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn = @isbn) " _
    & " BEGIN " _
    & " delete from published_by where isbn = @isbn; " _
    & " delete from return where isbn = @isbn; " _
    & " delete from issue where isbn = @isbn; " _
    & " delete from book where isbn = @isbn;" _
    & " SELECT 1; " _
    & " END " _
    & " ELSE SELECT 0", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@isbn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 13) _ 
 With {.Value = isbn})
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
            Dim returnValue As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            If returnValue = 1 Then
                lblAlert.Text = ""
                lblInfo.Text = "Deleted"
            Else
                lblAlert.Text = "No Record Available"
                lblInfo.Text = ""
            End If
        Catch sqlEx As SqlException
            Select sqlEx.Number
                Case -1, 2, 53
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed to Database")
            End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it change any UI? For example, you are setting some label text to "Deleted" or "No Record Available", does any of this happen?

Comment: You say that you are using a Stored Procedure. Stored Procedures live inside the SQL Server and you call them by name from your code. Why do you have the definition (full SQL) of the stored procedure in the code?

Comment: I think the semi-colons after the DELETE and SELECT statements might be the issue. Have you tried the code without these?

Comment: @YacoubMassad no it does not display the Labels text i.e. "Deleted"

Comment: @vmachan does semicolons have to do anything with this? but let me try without them!

Comment: Try to put square brackets around "return" like this: `delete from [return]`

Comment: but why @YacoubMassad brackets? and do I need to put only for return table or for other tables as well?

Comment: return is a reserved word

Comment: Oh ok just let me check about that

Comment: haha thank you it solved the problem @YacoubMassad

Comment: Are you storing ISBNs as String/Text now?  I was wondering how you would handle those with letters (`0-314-28544-X` which is a valid ISBN).  Are you using the check digit to validate them?

Comment: Yes after long time I took your advice and applied string datatype for ISBN although it was a headache @Plutonix

Comment: They could be an actual Type and include a method to validate if the digits entered are correct (the last digit is a check value)

Comment: And no currently I am only storing them like this `314-28544-0` I mean with no `x` and I have set validation to only accept numbers, dashes `( - )` and they must be in range of minimum 10 character and can not be more than 13 characters! @Plutonix

Comment: @Plutonix can you help me with last digit validation cause I am not an advance programmer like you, I even can't call myself a programmer :(

Comment: ...so you convert "X" to what? 0?  thats not correct - both 0 and 10(X) are valid check digits.  And the length of a formatted ISBN13 (with dashes) can be 15 or more.  I wouldnt use the dashes in the DB if it is the key because  the layout can vary by publisher block. `978-0-306-40615-7` is the same ISBN as `978-0-30-640615-7` but would not match in queries etc.

Comment: So what do you want me to do first strip ISBN from dashes and then store them in SQL with no dashes? and yeah also let the user to enter (X) or 0 at the end ? @Plutonix

Comment: I *might* do both - using a Type -  Use the numerals `9780306406157` or `31428544X` as the key.  But since you cant put an ISBN13 back to the same layout without knowing where the digits were, store the formatted value too.  Whether to store the formatted version or not would depend on whether using a generic format for them would confuse users. (ie they enter `978-0-30-640615-7` but after that it would show as maybe `978-0-306-40615-7`  in ISBN13 the 2nd and 3rd block can vary depending on the publisher quanity apparently.  (An ISBN Type could do both/either, of course)

Comment: @Plutonix I am getting confused let me summarize what should I do: I will store ISBNs with or without x but stripped out from dashes, and when I display ISBNs back to user I will just display it with no dashes and will inform the user that dashes are optional! is it ok now?

Comment: ***I*** would use the *exact* ISBN characters without dashes as the PK.  This would prevent any variety in the PK (X vs 0, dashes in wrong spot).  My `ISBN` class would add them back in to display to the user.  ISBN10 is a fixed format AFAICT.  If the ***users*** want the preserve the exact dash location in ISBN13. I'd save the formatted form also, otherwise my ISBN class would put them back in some generic fashion e.g. `###-##-####-###-#`.  The dashes are functional, so the user would see them.  They do not help us as a PK though

Comment: Thanks for all this help now my concept is clear :) you mentioned in your comment "ISBN class" can you do that as an example for me so I may use it in my project please? @Plutonix

Comment: Post a Q relating to the ISBN10 check digit validation and parts of it will leak out.  Naturally, you need to take a stab at it first and post code so it is a valid Q that doesnt get DVs

Comment: OK will do so later @Plutonix thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"return" is a reserved word (see [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)). To fix the issue, put it between square brackets like this:

```
delete from [return] where isbn ...
```

Another note about your code is that you are swallowing the `SqlException` in case the error number was not -1, 2, or 53. To fix this, handle the case where it is not one of these numbers like this:

```
Select Case sqlEx.Number
    Case -1, 2, 53
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Failed to Database")
    Case Else
        Console.WriteLine(....) 'write something here, you can use sqlEx.Message
End Select
```

This is the reason why you didn't get an error message in the first place.